# Differences between imported service reference and generated wsdl

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I imported a service reference using wsdl, this wsdl contains classes and methods, some of which to be implemented in my web service. Now, publishing my WS and trying to get the wsdl I notice a lot of differences between the imported one and the generated (namespaces, "ArrayOf" prefix in collections, ...).
I'm using just the classes provided by the original wsdl, so I can't understand why the wsdl of my WS has to be different...
I need to output a wsdl identical to the one imported because they will be both imported from my customer to make an interface, so everything has to be coincident.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, I don't see why your customer is being handed two WSDLs.

To simplify things just hand the generated WSDL from your web service to your customer. If there are things in the imported WSDL that are not in the generated WSDL I would just duplicate the missing pieces in your generated WSDL.

The generated WSDL probably contains more generic definitions of collections than what you provided so that it is compatible with different client languages.